How to download all items in the Sharepoint list in .csv format using graph api?
I have a scenario. I have list of items under Sharepoint lists. Currently using this api to fetch the field values as a response from the api query -
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/lists/{list-id}/items?$expand=fields. The response I am currently receiving needs a column name mapping from https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/lists/{list-id}/columns api. In this approach we need to call them separately, then map them and create a dataset out of it.
My question - "Is there any other option just to directly download the contents of all the items in the Sharepoint list using graph api or any other Sharepoint api in csv format or anything else?"
